# Proving that $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x^2-5x}{x^2+2}=-1$ using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

My attempt: 
$$
\left|\frac{x^2-5x}{x^2+2}+1\right|<\left|\frac{x^2-5x}{x^2+2}\right|<
\left|\frac{x^2-5x}{x^2}\right|<\frac{1}{x^2}|x^2-5x|,$$
using the restriction $|x-2|<2$, so $0<x<4$, thus
$$\frac{1}{x^2}|x^2-5x|=\frac{1}{x^2}|x^2-6x+4-4+x|=\frac{1}{x^2}|(x-2)^2+x-4|<\frac{(x-2)^2}{x^2}<\epsilon,$$
hence, due to the fact that $|x-2|<\delta\le2$ we get
$$
\delta^2<\epsilon x^2 < \epsilon16.
$$
Finally, for any $\epsilon >0$ the corresponding $\delta$ is $\min\{\epsilon, 4\epsilon^{1/2}\}$.

Is it correct?

Comment: The statement $\frac{1}{x^2}|(x-2)^2+x-4|<\frac{(x-2)^2}{x^2}$ is false.

Comment: Useful algebra: $\frac{x^2-5x}{x^2+2}+1=\frac{2x^2-5x+2}{x^2+2}=\frac{(x-2)(2x-1)}{x^2+2}$

Comment: @A.E Plugging in $x=1$ yields $2<1$

Comment: Note that to get $\epsilon$-$\delta$ instead of $\epsilon-\delta$ you should use the `$\epsilon$-$\delta$` construction. Also, you can use `\left` and `\right` to get properly sized delimiters (you can get even "more properly sized" delimiters using `\biggl` and stuff like that but I often just go with `\left` and `\right` because I am lazy.

Comment: I like these problems...out of curiosity, what's the source? I imagine you are doing these for homework, but are you using a particular text or are they problems your instructor created (if, indeed, these problems are for a class)?

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Regarding the problems - they are from a course workbook. So I guess they were created by the Instructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We have to find a number $\delta>0$ such that $\left|\frac{x^2-5x}{x^2+2}+1\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-2|<\delta$. But, as Andre notes,
$$
\left|\frac{x^2-5x}{x^2+2}+1\right|=\left|\frac{2x^2-5x+2}{x^2+2}\right|=|x-2|\left|\frac{2x-1}{x^2+1}\right|.
$$
We find a positive constant $C$ such that $\left|\frac{2x-1}{x^2+1}\right|<C\Rightarrow |x-2|\left|\frac{2x-1}{x^2+1}\right|<C|x-2|$, and we can make $C|x-2|<\epsilon$ by taking $|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{C}=\delta$. We restrict $x$ to lie in the interval $|x-2|<1$ and note the following:
\begin{align}
|x-2|<1&\implies 1<x<3\\[1em]
&\implies 1>\frac{1}{x}>\frac{1}{3}\\[1em]
&\implies 1>\frac{1}{x^2}>\frac{1}{9}\\[1em]
&\implies \frac{1}{3}>\frac{1}{x^2+2}>\frac{1}{11}\\[1em]
&\implies \frac{5}{3}>\frac{2x-1}{x^2+2}>\frac{1}{11}\\[1em]
&\implies C=\frac{5}{3}.
\end{align}
Thus, we should choose $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{3\epsilon}{5}\right\}$. To see that this choice of $\delta$ works, consider the following:

Given $\epsilon>0$, we let $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{3\epsilon}{5}\right\}$. If $|x-2|<1$, then $\left|\frac{2x-1}{x^2+2}\right|<\frac{5}{3}$. Also, $|x-2|<\frac{3\epsilon}{5}$. Hence,
$$
\left|\frac{x^2-5x}{x^2+2}+1\right|=|x-2|\left|\frac{2x-1}{x^2+1}\right|<\frac{3\epsilon}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{3}=\epsilon,
$$
as desired. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Wonderful answer. Thank you!

Comment: You sure accepted that awfully fast.  Can you guarantee it's valid?

Comment: @A.E Please make sure to read through it all and make sure you understand everything. There's easily a chance that I could have slipped up somewhere.

Comment: In $5/3 > (2x-1)/(x^2+2) > 5/11$ if I plug in $x=1^+$ then I get $1/3 > 5/11$?

Comment: @A.E Bingo! Yes, I was slightly careless there. Can you see how I muffed that up and how now the correction should suffice?

Comment: @Aweygan: Thank you for your concern. Besides the $5/3$ that - to the best of my understanding - can be replaced by some smaller value, It seems absolutely valid. So even if it contains some minor miscalculation(s) - the main idea is still there and wonderfully written. As for me, this (the idea) is the main thing.

Comment: @A.E My issue there was that I increased the numerator for each term by $4$, but $2x-1$ takes on a variable amount. It was correct to have $5/3$ because I needed to ensure that the "upper bound" was still correct when looking at the largest possible value for $x$, but when $x$ takes a smaller value, then the middle expression is not necessarily greater than the rightmost expression (if I added $4$ to the rightmost expression as I originally did). [Hopefully that made sense.]

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Sure. Thank you!

Comment: @A.E Sure thing `:-)` I enjoy answering when the OP shows a fair amount of work/effort on their end. Keep up the hard work.